# C++11 initializer lists on variadic template's parameters: why isn't this working

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Enclosing a variadic template's parameters in initializer lists should assure that they're evaluated in order, but isn't happening here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template<class T> void some_function(T var)
{
   cout << var << endl;
}

struct expand_aux {
    template<typename... Args> expand_aux(Args&&...) { }
};

template<typename... Args> inline void expand(Args&&... args) 
{
   bool b[] = {(some_function(std::forward<Args>(args)),true)...}; // This output is 42, "true", false and is correct
   cout << "other output" << endl;
   expand_aux  temp3 { (some_function(std::forward<Args>(args)),true)...  }; // This output isn't correct, it is false, "true", 42
}

int main()
{
   expand(42, "true", false);

   return 0;
}
```

How come?

Comment: Compiler bug?  From your provided link, switching from gcc to clang or Intel will produce the results you expect.

Comment: You're right Drew, clang is doing it right

Comment: (Or undefined behavior...)

Comment: I might be wrong, but could this an order of evaluation issue ? Is there anything forcing the calls so some_function to be evaluated in the order you are expecting ?

Edit: Got my answer from Andy Prowl. Thanks !

Comment: Just stick with the array, aggregate initialization in GCC respects left-to-right evaluation.

Comment: VC++ 2013 has the exact same problem. :-[ Reported here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1075443/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to be a **bug**. The output should be the one you are expecting.

While there is no guarantee on the order of evaluation of the arguments of a constructor call *in general*, there is a guarantee on the order of evaluation of expressions in an braced initializer list.

Per Paragraph 8.5.4/4 of the C++11 Standard:

> **Within the initializer-list of a braced-init-list, the initializer-clauses, including any that result from pack
>   expansions (14.5.3), are evaluated in the order in which they appear**. That is, every value computation and
>   side effect associated with a given initializer-clause is sequenced before every value computation and side
>   effect associated with any initializer-clause that follows it in the comma-separated list of the initializer-list.
>   [ Note: This evaluation ordering holds regardless of the semantics of the initialization; for example, **it applies
>   when the elements of the initializer-list are interpreted as arguments of a constructor call, even though
>   ordinarily there are no sequencing constraints on the arguments of a call**. —end note ]

Comment: seems gcc just applied it's normal function call argument evaluation order to uniform initialization calls that are normal constructor calls. But tbh, it's also a bit confusing that `Foo x{a,b};` and `Foo x(a,b);` are not the same even if the same constructor gets called.

Comment: @ArneMertz: Indeed, uniform initialization is *way* less uniform than it pretends to be.

Comment: I wouldn't say that. Having aggregate initializer lists evaluated left to right and non-aggregate the other way round is clearly not very uniform, regardless whether they had to be written with different braces/brackets in C++03. Imo it's a (now nonfixable) bug or at least an inconsistency in the standard that allowed compilers to evaluate function and especially constructor arguments to be evaluated right to left like gcc does. Defining the eval order is just the right thing to ensure portability between different compilers and would've been for function argument evaluation in the old days.

Comment: @ArneMertz: I think you got my sentence wrong. I was just agreeing with your statement that it is confusing. On the other hand, forcing the compiler to *always* evaluate left-to-right may prevent some optimizations. I'm not a compiler expert, so I'll shut up here - but I would expect that a good reason exists if the order of evaluation of the argument of regular function calls is unspecified.

Answer (score 4):

As noted, your problem is a compiler bug.  Your code, as written, should evaluate its arguments in order.

My advice would be to be explicit about what you want to do, and what order you are doing it in, and avoid abusing the comma operator (as an aside, your code could behave strangely if `some_function` returned a type that overrides `operator,`) or using initializer lists guarantees (which, while standard, are also relatively obscure).

My go to solution is to write and then use `do_in_order`:

```
// do nothing in order means do nothing:
void do_in_order() {}
// do the first passed in nullary object, then the rest, in order:
template<typename F0, typename... Fs>
void do_in_order(F0&& f0, Fs&&... fs) {
  std::forward<F0>(f0)();
  do_in_order( std::forward<Fs>(fs)... );
}
```

which you use like this:

```
do_in_order( [&]{ some_function(std::forward<Args>(args)); }... );
```

you wrap the action you want to do in an anonymous nullary full-capture lambda, then use `...` to create a whole set of instances of said lambdas and pass to `do_in_order`, which calls them in order via perfect forwarding.

This should be easy for a compiler to inline and reduce to a sequence of calls.  And it says what it does directly, and doesn't require strange void casts, the use of the comma operator, or arrays whose value is discarded.